Jetpack Compose - LazyColumn scroll not working when implementing paging and scrolling fast
Steps to Reproduce or Code Sample to Reproduce:

Implement paging with LazyColumn.
When last item is visible, add more items ino the list and keep trying to scroll continuously.
The items get added to the list but the scrolling seems to be stuck. Once you stop trying to scroll continuously and then try to scroll again after 1 sec, the list get's scrolled.

import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.border
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListState
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.rememberLazyListState
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.LaunchedEffect
import androidx.compose.runtime.derivedStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamily
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import apps.muxy.compose.MainViewModel
import apps.muxy.compose.ui.theme.ComposeTheme

@Composable
fun PaginatedList(
    viewModel: MainViewModel,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()
    val names = viewModel.names
    val loaderVisible = viewModel.loaderVisible

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) { viewModel.loadMore() }

    LazyColumn(state = lazyListState, modifier = modifier) {
        items(count = names.size, key = { names[it] }) {
            Name(names[it])
        }

        if (loaderVisible) {
            item { ListLoader() }
        }
    }

    OnBottomReached(lazyListState = lazyListState) { viewModel.loadMore() }
}

@Composable
private fun Name(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Text(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(horizontal = 8.dp, vertical = 4.dp)
            .border(width = 1.dp, color = Color.LightGray, shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp))
            .padding(12.dp),
        text = name,
        fontFamily = FontFamily.Monospace,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold
    )
}

@Composable
private fun ListLoader() {
    Box(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(40.dp)
            .background(Color.Red)
    )
}

@Composable
private fun OnBottomReached(lazyListState: LazyListState, buffer: Int = 0, loadMore: () -> Unit) {
    val shouldLoadMore = remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            val lastVisibleItem =
                lazyListState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.lastOrNull()
                    ?: return@derivedStateOf false
            lastVisibleItem.index >= lazyListState.layoutInfo.totalItemsCount - buffer - 1
        }
    }

    LaunchedEffect(shouldLoadMore.value) {
        if (shouldLoadMore.value) {
            loadMore()
        }
    }
}

ViewModel
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlin.time.Duration.Companion.seconds

class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {

    var names by mutableStateOf<List<String>>(mutableListOf())
    var loaderVisible by mutableStateOf(false)
    private var currentIndex = 0

    fun loadMore() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            loaderVisible = true
            delay(5.seconds)

            val mutableNames = names.toMutableList()
            for (i in currentIndex..(currentIndex + PAGE_COUNT)) {
                mutableNames.add("Name $i")
            }
            currentIndex += PAGE_COUNT
            currentIndex++

            loaderVisible = false
            names = mutableNames
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val PAGE_COUNT = 20
    }
}

